# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL when trying to access port 3000 on AWS EC2 with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm following this tutorial where they are setting up a express server and when you go to the DNS you see your response (in this case HEY!), this is the link to the tutorial https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171

But when I do it gives me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL, but the tutorial doesn't even mention anything about SSL and gets it to work.

This is my code

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('HEY!')
})
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'))
```

This is my security group (outbound rules is set to all traffic)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP client/browser likely tried to establish an HTTP**S**/SSL connection and not an unencrypted HTTP connection to your server.

Make sure that you do not use `https://...` when accessing the HTTP endpoint from your client/browser, but use `http://...`. If you use a modern browser for this (Google Chrome for example), you likely need to go into the address bar and manually specify `http://` as the URL scheme.

You can also simply test via any other HTTP client, like cURL, wget, Postman, etc.